# A truncation occurred during evaluation of the expression

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, ssis, business-intelligence, truncation

I keep getting this error on an **SSIS for loop container**
Error: A truncation occurred during evaluation of the expression. The truncation occurred during evaluation, which may include any point in an intermediate step.

The container on it self is running and doing what it's suppose to do but once it's finished the whole package fails as a workaround i forced the package execution result to be always successful
but it's not a long term solution

Here are my for loop container params

```
variable HstartDate = 01/01/2021

initExpression @HstartDate   =   substring(@HstartDate,7,4) +"-" + substring (@HstartDate,4,2)+"-" + substring (@HstartDate,1,2) 

evalExpression (DT_DATE) @HstartDate <=  GETDATE()

AssignExpression  @HstartDate =  DATEADD("dd" ,1, (DT_DATE) @HstartDate  )
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `HstartDate = 01/01/2021`? That would assign start date the value 0 if it's an integer type value. `1/1/2021 = 1/2021 = 0.000494804552202 ≈ 0`

Comment: actually it's a string type

Comment: Why? It should be a date datatype.

Comment: Thank you for replying if i set it to date datatype it would give me 10/02/2021 13:59:55
but i need the date formt to be YYYY-MM-DD 
 so i declared it as string YYYY/MM/DD  then used substring to get the YYYY-MM-DD  format